# не работает ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

**brands.html**
 
    
        
            Brands

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a ui-sref="dashboard.addbrand"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add New Brand</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" ng-controller="brandCtrl">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nume</th>
                        <th>Manager de brand</th>
                        <th>Adresa Web</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="brand in brands" >
                        <td>{{brand.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{brand.brandManager}}</td>
                        <td>>{{brand.adresa}}</td>
                        <td><a ui-sref="dashboard.editbrand"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                        </button></a></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <!-- /.table-responsive -->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Nume:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Manager de brand:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="manager-name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Logo:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="logo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label >La Pachet:</label>
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="packet" id="packetYes">Yes</label>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="packet" id="packetNo">No</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="packet" id="packetNo">No</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Reservarea Masa:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Livrarea:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Adresa:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Descriere:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Filiala:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
```

**brandCtrl.js**

```
    'use strict';
     var app = angular.module('sbAdminApp', []);
     app.controller("brandCtrl", function ($scope) {
     $scope.brands = [
        {name: 'Star Kebab', brandManager: 'Roma Mosienco', adresa: 'str.Ion     Cuza'},
        {name: 'Star Kebab', brandManager: 'Roma Mosienco', adresa: 'str.Ion Cuza'}
    ];
});
```

Comment: что значит не работает?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вроде все работает, ниже ваш код, с добавлением обертки `<div ng-app="sbAdminApp">..</div>` и подключением angular/bootstrap (нажмите на `Выполнить код`).

```js
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('sbAdminApp', []);
 app.controller("brandCtrl", function ($scope) {
 $scope.brands = [
    {name: 'Star Kebab2', brandManager: 'Roma Mosienco', adresa: 'str.Ion     Cuza'},
    {name: 'Star Kebab', brandManager: 'Roma Mosienco', adresa: 'str.Ion Cuza'}
];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div ng-app="sbAdminApp">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <a ui-sref="dashboard.addbrand"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add New Brand</button></a>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example" ng-controller="brandCtrl">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nume</th>
            <th>Manager de brand</th>
            <th>Adresa Web</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th> 
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="brand in brands">
            <td>{{brand.name}}</td>
            <td>{{brand.brandManager}}</td>
            <td>>{{brand.adresa}}</td>
            <td><a ui-sref="dashboard.editbrand"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                        </button></a></td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                        </button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.table-responsive -->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form role="form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Nume:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Manager de brand:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="manager-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Logo:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="logo">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>La Pachet:</label>
                <div class="radio">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="packet" id="packetYes">Yes</label>
                  <label><input type="radio" name="packet" id="packetNo">No</label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                  <label><input type="radio" name="packet" id="packetNo">No</label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Reservarea Masa:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Livrarea:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Adresa:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Descriere:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Filiala:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```